# can't open developer tools(F12) in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I can't open the developer tools in my Internet Explorer. Clicking this option has no effect. Is there something wrong with my browser? I don't know how to fix it, or do I need to reinstall it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the IE browser to check whether it fixes the issue.

Alternatively, try to press the F12 key to check whether Developer tools get opened or not.

If the issue persists then try to Reset the IE browser. It can help to solve this issue.

you can go to Tools -> Internet options -> Advanced tab

Click on the Reset button to reset the IE browser.